# Select menu loses focus

Tags: jquery

When clicking "Click Me", the text turns into a select menu. When changing the select menu, it updates the text.

Last thing I need to do is if the select menu loses focus (i.e. something other than the select menu is clicked), revert back to the original text. How do I do this?

Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/tBRf8/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title>Select Clones</title>
<style type="text/css">
.hide {display:none;}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#my-table tbody').append($("#row-clone").clone(true).removeAttr('id'));
    })

    $("#my-table td.edit")
    .on("click", "span", function(){
        var $t    = $(this),
        $html = $t.parent(),
        role  = $t.text();
        $html.html($("#select-clone").clone(true).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').focus().blur(function() {alert('Handler for .blur() called.')}));
        //$html.html($("#select-clone").clone(true).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class'));
    })
    .on("change", "select", function() {
        var $t = $(this),
        val   = $('<span>').html($t.find(':selected').html());
        $t.parent().html(val);
    });

    //$('#select-clone').blur(function() {alert('Handler for .blur() called.')});
    //$('#select-clone').focusout(function() {alert('Handler for .focusout() called.')});

});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="my-table">
  <thead class="hide">
    <tr id="row-clone"><td></td><td class="edit"><span>Click Me</span></td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td class="edit"><span>Click Me</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td class="edit"><span>Click Me</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td class="edit"><span>Click Me</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<select id="select-clone" class="hide">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<button id="add">Add</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("td.edit select").focus();` to focus on the select box when it is shown, and then use the blur event:

```
$('#select-clone').blur(function () {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This almost works.  Unfortunately, user needs to open the select menu first.  Maybe a way to use jQuery to apply focus?

Comment: In what way does it not work? The user should be able to select something before it loses focus.

Comment: You click "click me" and the select menu appears.  Then immediately click something else, the the event doesn't trigger.  You must first click the select menu, then click off it and it triggers.

Comment: Oh, try `$('.select-clone').focus();` to give it focus when it appears.

Comment: Just updated to use class per your post, but still doesn't work.  http://jsfiddle.net/tBRf8/8/

Comment: Just tried $html.find('select').focus(); and it appears to work!  Any thoughts on a cleaner way to code it?

Comment: Oh, I was in jsfiddle and I just saw your post. I finally got `$("td.edit select").focus();` to work, which is similar to what you have. I froze my browser though with all those popups in the `blur` function! Haha

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do you mind updating your answer so I can selected it as answered.